# Rules for Require in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Recently im working on new Nodejs project and find some codes like this :

```
function a(){
   var http = require('http');
   var fs = require('fs');
}

function b(){
   var path = require('path');
   var http = require('http');
}

function c(){
  var fs = require('fs');
 }
```

so i have a some question about coding like this :

- is require have some rules for using it?
- is it good using rquire on top of codes or when we need it call it.
- is coding like this make conflict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some rules for when to call `require`:

- By default, require a module globally once at the start of the file and do not reassign the variable to which the result of `require` is assigned.
- If requiring a module has been proved to impact performance significantly (maybe it has initialization routines that take a long time to run) and it is not used throughout the file, then require it locally, inside the function that needs it.
- If the module's name must be computed in a function, then load it locally.

If the code you show in your question is all in one file and is meant to be used in production, I'd ask the coder who produced it what warrants using `require` in that way, and if a good, substantial reason, supported by evidence cannot be formulated, I'd tell this coder to move the `require` calls to the start of the file.

Comment: Since node modules are [cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), the code shouldn't be executed multiple times.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the second sentence of my comment. How then could requiring a module impact performance, since they are cached? Moreover, why not impact performance at startup, so that during the execution the code will run fast?

Comment: I went into those details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892601/requirejs-performance-of-multiple-calls-to-require/19894938#19894938). That question was about RequireJS but the main principles are the same as for Node.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should avoid these in production. Modules are cached indeed, so it can affect performance only during initial calls to `require`, but still it can. Also `fs`, `http` and and `path` are built-in modules, so `require`-ing them doesn't involve reading from disk, only code compilation and execution, but if you use non built-in modules you will also block event loop for the time of reading from disk.

In general, if you use any `sync` functions, including `require`, you should use them only during first tick, since no servers are listening yet anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Manning publication has a good book about node, called **Node.js in action** this is how the node's module requiring rules described it.
 [image]